# ServiceStack EnryptedClient use IReturnVoid DTO error

Tags: c#, .net, servicestack, httpserver

I have an EncryptedClient for my Service like this

```
_jsonClient = new JsonServiceClient(baseUrl);
string publicKeyXml = _jsonClient.Get(new GetPublicKey());
_encryptedCient = _jsonClient.GetEncryptedClient(publicKeyXml);
_encryptedCient.SessionId = authResponse.SessionId;
```

and a DTO

```
public class AlarmNotification : IReturnVoid, IHasSessionId
{
    public string SessionId { get; set; }
}
```

the handler method in service does not really matter, when i call

```
_encryptedCient.Send(new AlarmNotification { });
```

It hits the server, request is processed correctly but after Service finished the processing I get ArgumentNullException, stating that some string named "s" is referencing a null. If I use any other return type except IReturnVoid, everything works fine. Any ideas why this happens are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bug that should now be [resolved from this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/950603e252e8b7c93a7dd751ff973a12591618ef).

This change is available from v4.0.53 that's now [available on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet).

Comment: strange but even after updating to 4.0.53 the issue is still there, but i have deleted packages cache and packages from my solution.

Comment: @HardLuck weird, did you also delete NuGet cache in `%LOCALAPPDATA%\NuGet\Cache\` ?

Comment: yes, and checked it manually that there is nothing left, i even tried reisntalling all the packages for solution. I have also checked the Send method reference - ServiceStack.Interfaces.4.0.53

Comment: @HardLuck ok I've been repro the issue with v4.0.53 packages, now investigating why...

Comment: @HardLuck Looks like a MyGet caching issue, the ServiceStack NuGet package CI created doesn't have the issue whilst downloading the package from MyGet does. I'm redeploying to MyGet and will check to see that it gets the latest .dlls. Will let you know the new version is up on MyGet.

Comment: @HardLuck ok looks like MyGet is updated with the latest .dll